# Ode to the heroes, vanquisher of puzzles

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, metapuzzles

These heroes, although not as rare as you might think as a new one is born every 2 weeks, are precious gems appreciated by all. Sometimes all you can do is **stare** at them, other times you can't help but **cheer** them.

This ode is not only about these heroes though, but also about their vanquishers!
Their knowledge accumulated herein, forms a word that unites us all.

Oh mighty aspiring heroes, absorb the following knowledge and find the message! This important message must be exchanged with everyone for it needs many readers!

> - Mighty hero, why have you fallen to such a monstrous beast. Loved by all you were. To teach us history is all you wanted. Never shall I forget the first quote of Mr. Joseph you taught us. Sorry only may I say that I have forgotten his family name.
> - Oh fallen hero, master of images and Russian dolls, how cheered you were, until the time of your demise came fourth.
> - Praising oneself is far from honorable, but a hero nonetheless you were. Everyone looked up to you. You were known for your love of animals, especially that one rare bird.
> - Your vanity is insatiable and come back from the dead have you, to be looked upon you wanted, only to be vanquished once more disguised as a master of patterns. The five letter word that was your last still echos into your fading consciousness.
> - Our last hero was a master of words. His words could really speak to us. The one who slayed him should be ashamed, for all he wanted was to play. I regret to say that I have forgotten the name of this unforgettable hero, all I can recall is the third letter.

**HINT**

> Each hint gives 1 letter, the order is important.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The final answer is:

> **STACK**

**____**

One is born every 2 weeks
Sometimes all you can do is stare at them, other times you can't help but cheer them.

> They are the Fortnightly Topic Challenges, whose puzzles are then tallied for highest **views** (stares) and highest **votes** (cheers).

The first bullet point is for -

> **[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #14: History](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5275/fortnightly-topic-challenge-14-history)**
>  "Loved by all" says look at **highest-voted**: **[And the rest is hstr!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41375/and-the-rest-is-hstr) by IAmInPLS**.
>    ("fallen to such a monstrous beast" references that this puzzle was solved by Beastly Gerbil.)
>  The "quote of Mr. Joseph" references
>    'Ideas are far more powerful than guns. We don't let our people have guns.
>    Why should we let them have ideas?' - Joseph Stalin
>  so gives **S**TALIN

The second bullet point is for -

> **[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #26: Rebus](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/fortnightly-topic-challenge-26-rebus)**
>  "images and Russian dolls" references **[Rematry oshkabus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48889/rematry-oshkabus) by Sp3000**,
>    which combines both in its name.
>  That puzzle's answer is REC**T**IFIED — of which we take the *fourth*.

The third bullet point is for -

> **[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #22: Animals](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5677/fortnightly-topic-challenge-22-animals)**
>  "Everyone looked up to you" says look at **most viewed**: **[My friend is quite silly](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46874/my-friend-is-quite-silly) by stack reader**.
>    ("Praising oneself" references that this puzzle was set by OP.)
>  The rare bird reference points to the **A**LBATROSS in that puzzle.

The fourth bullet point is for -

> **[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #20: Pattern](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/fortnightly-topic-challenge-20-pattern)**
>  "To be looked upon" says look at **most viewed**: **[Find the secret word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45893) by stack reader**.
>    ("Your vanity is insatiable..." references that this puzzle was again set by OP.)
>  "five letter word that was your last" is the puzzle answer, MAGI**C** — of which we take the *last*.

The fifth bullet point is for -

> **[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #25: Wordplay](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5759/fortnightly-topic-challenge-25-wordplay)**
>  "His words could really speak to us" references **[I never knew my words could speak!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48397/i-never-knew-my-words-could-speak)**
>    **by Ankoganit** — which was **most favorited**.
>  The vanquisher is AN**K**OGANIT — of which we take the third.
>    (The "heroes" are the FTC topics, and "vanquishers" the winners; should "the name of this unforgettable hero" refer to a vanquisher instead?)

Assemble what we've found, and it gives

> **STACK**

Comment: For you to figure out so much so quickly is both amazing and frustrating haha. As one would expect from the mighty Hero Rubio, vanquisher of puzzles. But the 2 last letters are wrong. The last one is a bit different than the others.(was not enough challenges to make up good words so I had to improvise a little.)

Comment: Yah, I'm updating thanks to some suggestions in TSL

Comment: Ankoganit created the puzzle. M Oehm vanquished it.